# Debian 10, bluetooth won't work

Tags: debian, bluetooth

On Debian 10.

lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [8086:3397]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.146045] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    1.057956] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[   19.892043] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   19.892054] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   19.892057] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   19.892059] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   19.892062] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   47.713024] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   47.713025] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   47.713028] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 1136.120867] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[ 1136.120875] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[ 1136.120882] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 1148.781833] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200c tx timeout
[ 1148.781836] Bluetooth: hci0: failed to disable LE scan: status 0x1f
[ 1176.429576] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0409 tx timeout
[ 1342.827796] Bluetooth: hci0: failed to disable LE scan: status 0x1f
[ 1342.827799] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200c tx timeout
```

systemctl status bluetooth.service:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-05-24 07:55:44 CEST; 1h 12min ago
         Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
     Main PID: 1882 (bluetoothd)
       Status: "Running"
        Tasks: 1 (limit: 1995)
       Memory: 1.6M
       CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
               └─1882 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

    May 24 08:17:05 homeserver bluetoothd[1882]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
    May 24 08:17:05 homeserver bluetoothd[1882]: RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
    May 24 08:17:05 homeserver bluetoothd[1882]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.330 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
    May 24 08:17:05 homeserver bluetoothd[1882]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.330 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
    May 24 08:17:05 homeserver bluetoothd[1882]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.107 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
    May 24 08:17:05 homeserver bluetoothd[1882]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.107 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
    May 24 08:23:39 homeserver bluetoothd[1882]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.330 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
    May 24 08:23:39 homeserver bluetoothd[1882]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.330 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
    May 24 08:23:39 homeserver bluetoothd[1882]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.107 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
    May 24 08:23:39 homeserver bluetoothd[1882]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.107 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

bluetoothctl:

```
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# show
No default controller available
```

Comment: I see your problem, but I do not know exactly what is your question. Anyway, if you want to get it to work then I suggest you try to install [blueman](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/blueman), it did miracles for me on Fedora. Unfortunately I do not have much knowledge about the underlying processes (so I also really don't know if blueman will solve your problem, but very small effort to try out).

Comment: I already tried blueman, to no avail.